# Djang views and urls connect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

App folder `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def MyApp(request):
    return HttpResponse("HELLO APP")
```

App folder `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('MyApp/', views.MyApp, name='MyApp'),
]
```

Project folder `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('MyApp.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

When trying to open http://127.0.0.1:8000 I get the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in FirstProject.urls, Django tried these URL
patterns, in this order: MyApp/ [name='MyApp'] admin/ The empty path
didn’t match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a route defined for the empty path (i.e. `http://<hostname>/`). When you include another app's URL definitions, the two paths are concatenated, so currently the only valid paths in your project are:

```
'' (from main urls.py)  + '/MyApp/' (from app/urls.py)
'admin/` (from main urls.py)
```

Change the following line

```py
path('MyApp/', views.MyApp, name='MyApp'),
```

to

```py
path('', views.MyApp, name='MyApp'),
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect Django views and URLs, you need to define a URL pattern for each view in your `urls.py` file.

```py
# views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, World!")
```

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import hello_world

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]
```